# How to wrap text in background boxes

Tags: html, css

I am trying to wrap background color around text with css as seen in the screenshot below

[image]

Right now here is what i have but its not giving me what i really want

```
h2 {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

but this is what am getting

[image]

So anyone know what i need to add to make the text be wrapped with some padding?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you with what you need:

```css
body {
  background: #ddd;
}

p {
  background: #e87;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 29px;
  display: inline;
  box-shadow:0.2em 0 0 #e87,-0.2em 0 0 #e87;
  -moz-box-shadow:0.2em 0 0 #e87,-0.2em 0 0 #e87;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0.2em 0 0 #e87,-0.2em 0 0 #e87;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat?</p>
```

Comment: i want the wrap to end when the text ends on that line, you solution ia a full rectangle and fits all text per line in there...please check the first screenshot to see how the wrapping works for each line length

Answer (score 3):

You can use `line-height: 100%;` to avoid the vertical space between the lines:

```css
body {
  background: #ddd;
}

p {
  display: inline;
  line-height: 100%;
  background: #fa0;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
```

Comment: where is the padding or space in left and right? AND also can you use my current code and add stuffs there? right now you have `body` and `p` but i only have `h2` tag in my question